# Algebraic Arc Definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am searching for an elegant/compact definition/description of an arc into the algebraic domain given 2 points and ...(?) that allow to define every arc.
I know it is possible to define the arc given 2 points and the center or radius and a direction , I don't like so much because it can be inconsistent use too much data etc...
I know the usage of the bulge but it is not in the algebraic domain.
Is it possible to define the arc only using one another parameter?
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The best I know is the following.

For any scheme $X$ one can define the arc space $Hom(\mathbb{C}[[t]],X)$. You should think of the arc space as arcs given by a point, then a derivative, then a second derivative...

The functor $X\rightarrow Hom(\mathbb{C}[[t]],X)$ is representable.